# Употребление слова "погром" в отношении беспорядков в США

Tags: лексика, семантика

В русскоязычных СМИ употребляют слово "погром" в отношении текущих беспорядков в США. Правильное ли это употребление?

В моем понимании слово "погром" относится к насилию в отношении определенных групп общества, например погромы евреев в Российской империи или погромы греков в Стамбуле.

Согласно словарю Ожегова:

> Погром
>   -а, м. 1. Шовинистическое выступление против какой-н. национальной или иной группы населения, сопровождающееся грабежом и убийствами.
>   Каратели учинили п. 2. Полный беспорядок; разгром (разг.). В квартире
>   настоящий п.1 II прил. погромный, -ая, -ое (к 1 знач.).

В отношении второго значения я считаю, что фраза "в квартире настоящий погром" содержит иронию — бытовой беспорядок сравнивается с грабежами и убийствами. Употребление такой иронии в СМИ мне кажется неуместным.

Когда СМИ говорят о текущих погромах в США, подразумевают ли они, что эти беспорядки направлены против определенных групп, например против белого населения? (что, мне кажется, было бы неверным трактованием событий).

Если СМИ не имеют это в виду, правильно ли употребление слова "погром" в отношении протестов и беспорядков? Или слово "погромы" стало синонимом слова "беспорядки"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В средине прошлого века (когда составлялся словарь Ожегова) я бы частично согласился с Вами, наверное. Но язык развивается, некоторые слова за какую-нибудь сотню лет могут существенно изменить своё значение. Поэтому в сомнительных случаях лучше сверяться также с современными словарями. Например, [словарь Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC&all=x) говорит:

> **ПОГРОМ**, -а; м. 1. Разгром, разорение, опустошение. Устроить в квартире п. В комнате всё разбросано, просто п. какой-то. 2.
>   Шовинистическое выступление против какой-л. национальной или
>   социальной группы населения, сопровождающееся разграблением имущества
>   и убийствами. *Еврейский п. Призывы к погромам караются законом.*

Даже в уголовном праве термин **погром** употребляется в ст. 212 УК РФ как одно из проявлений массовых беспорядков. При этом под **погромом** понимается уничтожение или разрушение имущества, транспорта, средств связи, которые нередко сопровождаются насилием, издевательством над людьми, совершением убийств, изнасилованиями, разбойными нападениями, хищениями и т.п.

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) (который полезно смотреть для поиска современных значений и анализа тенденций, но не следует использовать как авторитетный источник) вообще не упоминает "шовинистическое" толкование:

> 1. беззаконные насильственные действия, совершаемые толпой, группами людей и включающие грабёж, убийства и разрушение имущества ◆ *Несмотря
>      на то, что волну массовых погромов удалось остановить, обстановка в
>      крае остается сложной, чреватой новыми рецидивами.* «Заявления и
>      сообщения», 2004 г. // «Дипломатический вестник» (цитата из
>      Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)
> 2. полный беспорядок, разгром ◆ *И все это, надо заметить, делалось у нее как-то без всякой трескотни и погрома и всегда весело.* Д.В.
>      Григорович, «Недолгое счастье», 1884 г. (цитата из Национального
>      корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)

Comment: Ох, невольно повторил ваш ответ (частично). Надеюсь, в обиде не будете.

Comment: @behemothus Наоборот, порадуюсь совпадению взглядов :)

Answer (score 2):

> Когда СМИ говорят о текущих погромах в США, подразумевают ли они, что эти беспорядки направлены против определенных групп,

Надо смотреть конкретный пример использования, но в принципе - да, такое вполне может предполагаться.

> например против белого населения?

Да, и против него тоже. Во всяком случае для российских СМИ такие трактовки - дело привычное. Но в первую очередь имеется в виду, что протесты направлены против среднего класса, торговцев и проч.

> (что, мне кажется, было бы неверным трактованием событий)

А почему, позвольте поинтересоваться?! Мы же говорим не о сути явления, а о том, как оно подается в СМИ, а в наше время журналистов ничто не ограничивает в выборе средств и трактовок, кроме их личных моральных принципов (которые тоже далеко не у всех журналистов на высоте).

Добавлю, что словарю Ожегова больше полувека, современная трактовка дает более широкое толкование понятия погрома, не замыкаясь на "национальных и иных" группах (последнее делает оговорку несколько бессмысленной - любое множество людей, числом больше двух - уже "иная группа"), а говорит о социальных группах (БТС Кузнецова, к примеру - http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC&all=x).

При такой трактовке поводов для ваших сомнений еще меньше.

Answer (score 0):

У слова "погром" есть два значения: прямое и переносное. Прямое общеизвестно, а переносное появилось в перестроечную и постперестроечную эпоху, когда слово "погром" стало иногда употребляться в смысле "культурный погром". Впервые я встретил это словоупотребление где-то в 90-е применительно к пресловутому постановлению о журналах "Ленинград" и "Звезда". Встречал его и применительно к т.н. "реформам": скажем, погром российского образования или погром российской науки.

Теперь по сути вопроса.  Если рассматривать нынешние события в США лишь как действия уличных банд, то это явление коррелирует лишь c погромом в буквальном смысле. И можно спорить о том, насколько сильна эта корреляция.

Если, однако, различить в американских событиях и куда более глубокий и важный аспект -- бунт дикарства против цивилизации (каковой бунт включает в себя интеллектуальный распад и хаос в умах образованного сословия) -- то тогда выстраивается корреляция и с переносным значением слова "погром".

С учётом этого обстоятельства, употребление термина "погром" применительно к американским событиям кажется мне допустимым.